Specify github actions runner location
I'm trying to set up a job on github to fetch some data using Binance API. However, binance blocks IPs from the US so the job keeps failing.
Is it possible to specify the geographical location of the runner to be in Europe?

I don't know that you can - I think you have to use their Azure US locations or self-host: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24969

Using a Proxy
In cases where you need to route requests through a proxy server, you can configure environment variables in your workflow. For example, you can use a service like TrustedProxies and set up the following environment variables:
env:
  - name: http_proxy
    value: "http://proxy.example.com:8080"
  - name: https_proxy
    value: "http://proxy.example.com:8080"
  - name: no_proxy
    value: "127.0.0.1,*.example.com"

This setup specifies the HTTP/HTTPS proxies to use along with the addresses or domains to exclude (no_proxy).

Using a Self-Hosted Runner
If you prefer more control over your workflow execution, you can set up a self-hosted runner. This allows you to host the runner on any machine or environment of your choice, enabling greater flexibility and control over the runner's operations.

